# CFSELECT Binding

Tags: coldfusion

I have a CFC that I want to use to populate Select Drop downs. The CFC has one argument

I'm trying to pass in the the argument that I want, not based on another field.

Is this possible? I've tried several variations and nothing.

```
<cfselect class="select" 
name="bordersize" 
id="bordersize" 
bind="cfc:/BBQ/CFC/ColorLookDropDowns.DropDowns(SelectedDropDown=bordersize)"
```

Comment: does your cfc work properly if you invoke it from coldfusion?  Is the access set to remote for the DropDowns function?

Answer (score -1):

quotes around bordersize works great.

```
<cfselect class="select" name="bordersize" id="bordersize" bind="cfc:/BBQ/CFC/ColorLookDropDowns.DropDowns(SelectedDropDown='bordersize')"
```

Hopefully this helps others.